# Views date filter in calendar (filter in range)

Tags: views, datetime

I add a node to the calendar start date 03/10/2015 and end date 15/03/2015.
In the view, I would like to do a filter that returns this node by entering the date 03/12/2015. Is it possible? I can't do that :/

Comment: I found a solution, this module is exactly what I needed: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter